# How to connect external GPU output to laptop display ?. Is it possible?

Tags: laptop, display, gpu, video-conversion

I have external GPU GTX 670 in my laptop connected via riser pci-e and I'd like to connect GPU output directly to laptop display which has hardware identifier in device manager

```
MONITOR\AUO46EC
```

Laptop model is

```
Acer E5-571G
```

I want to do this because I didn't find option of how to use eGPU for 3D rendering on laptop embedded display - when GTX 670 is connected then dGPU GTX 820M doesn't work and there is no option in NVIDIA Control Panel to select GTX 670 as default for 3D rendering. Anyway connecting eGPU directly to display works faster. Is there any ready video converter which can be bought for such purpose ?. I found that
    https://propix.com.pl/pl/p/Konwerter-RTD2660H-HDMIVGAAV-na-RGB-LVDS-RTD2660H/771
but I don't know if it's compatible device and anyway it's output resolution is different then my laptop's display (1366x768)

Comment: How should this work? Tthere are 3 PCIe lines on your laptop:

PCIe 3.0 is occupied by soldered nVidia GPU (8GT/s) GTX 820M

PCIe 2.0 (5GT/s) by wifi card

PCIe 2.0 (5GT/s) shared by LAN card and Card Reader - So you have to use the soldered GTX 820M, the eGPU would only work if your model would not have an internal dGPU. So buying extra hardware changes nothing

Comment: I replaced wifi card with riser cable then connected cable to riser with eGPU and eGPU works but only on external display

Comment: when eGPU starts then nVidia dGPU has problem code 43

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 PCIe lines on your laptop:

- PCIe 3.0 is occupied by soldered nVidia GPU (8GT/s) GTX 820M
- PCIe 2.0 (5GT/s) by wifi card - is x2 so no good choice for eGPU due to limited bandwidth
- PCIe 2.0 (5GT/s) shared by LAN card and Card Reader -

So you can use the soldered GTX 820M and the eGPU from a hardware perspective as you replaced the Wifi Card. As you get error 43 (Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)), you have found out that its not working.
Reason: Acer has no option in the BIOS to disable the dGPU (uses Optimus technology) so all graphics are routed (on a hardware basis) through the iGPU and changes between iGPU and dGPU are done automatically. So whatever you add causes the  dGPU to fail.
So only one of them (dGPU/eGPU) will work and the internal display rendered useless. The Acers E5-5xxY are a bad choice for modding with eGPU, due to the bandwidth on the PCIe-2 (x2) and the therefore limited perfomance (do not look at PC measured benchmarks divide them minimum by 10 to 20 to get the a realistic maximum value).
There are no success reports (on Windows) for Acers E5-5xxY eGPU modding (even with modded bios, payed programs and other tricks).
For Linux there are software solutions (software muxxing) where you can use the internal display with the eGPU. If you want to go that way search for

- Bumblebee (Nvidia) or
- Nvidia Prime (Nvidia) or
- Optimus prime

Comment: You mentioned Linux. What about Windows ?

Comment: As I wrote There are no success reports (on Windows) - so not possible due to how BIOS/EFI/Windoes and driver model interact.

Comment: For Windows I thought about this: Virtual VGA on eGPU output and remote display using Radmin Server and Radmin Viwer (it's pretty fast for half-hd) but when I tested Radmin on PC then Radmin Viewer doesn't display 3D fulscreen app

Comment: As I said stop wasting your time with those work arounds ,if you solve one problem you will face the next. If your internal dGPU works use this it will in the end have nearly the speed/performance of those external hacky unstable solutions

Comment: I'd play some older games on eGPU eg. Tomb Rider 2013 - it's approx 7 times faster on gtx 670 then gtx 820m and not only in it's in-build benchmark it works pretty well. What about video converter mentioned in my question ?. Could I connect eGPU to laptop display via it ?